# Shape.OnAction Does Not Include Underscore in Sheet Name Causing Error After Copying Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is used as a template for others. The template document is locked for editing, so the end users have to 'Save As' with the specifics for their project.

This template includes multiple sheets to incorporate all the possible layout options. Since most of the folks I work with are neither experienced nor comfortable with Excel, I have hidden all of the sheets. They first navigate to the *BASE_Start* sheet where they enter key information to determine which sheets should be unhidden based on the needs of their project. After entering the key information, the users click an *Activate* button(Form Control) that uses a macro, (BaseTabSelection), to unhide the sheets that are needed for their current project.

When the user tries to use the *Activate* button in the newly saved workbook, it still refers to the template workbook. To correct this, I have added the following subs (which I did not compile):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call ShapeUpdate
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub ShapeUpdate()
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim MacroLink As String
Dim SplitLink As Variant
Dim NewLink As String

For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    MacroLink = Shp.OnAction
    If MacroLink <> "" And InStr(MacroLink, "!") <> 0 Then
        SplitLink = Split(MacroLink, "!")
        NewLink = SplitLink(1)
        If Right(NewLink, 1) = "'" Then NewLink = Left(NewLink, Len(NewLink) - 1)
    End If
Next Shp

End Sub
```

I have used this code with success in many other workbooks, but it isn't working as expected in this workbook. The sheet name with the *Activate* button contains an underscore *BASE_Start*, but the underscore isn't included in the *MacroLink* variable that is assigned using *Shp.OnAction*.
[Code and watch window showing MacroLink was assigned using incorrect tab name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YelnZ.png)

The expected *MacroLink* variable value: [*ActiveWorkbook*]!**BASE_Start**.BaseTabSelection
The actual *MacroLink* variable value: [*ActiveWorkbook*]!**BASEStart**.BaseTabSelection

Does anyone know why the underscore in the sheet name would be ignored/removed in this case?

I have been able to create a workaround to add the underscore using the code below. However, this solution is limited to this workbook because the sheet name is known and *shouldn't* change.

```
If InStr(NewLink, "BASEStart") Then NewLink = Replace(NewLink, "BASEStart", "BASE_Start")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I needed to reassign the macro to the button in the template document.

Explanation: At the time the button was initially created, the sheet name has been *BASE Start* and the code name had been *BASEStart* (no underscore). As a result of unrelated complications, I'd updated the name and code name of this sheet to align with other sheets in the workbook.

After reading @Siddharth's answer, I had the idea to see if that old name had been saved somewhere. While looking at the OnAction value for the shape in the Watch Window in VBE, I realized I hadn't reassigned the macro after renaming the sheet. Since I hadn't made any changes to the macro name and the button was still working in the template, it hadn't occurred to me that changing the sheet name and sheet code name would impact the button.

[image: Watch Window: On Action Value]

A huge thank you to @Siddharth for your help and the inspiration!

Answer (score 4):

> The expected MacroLink variable value: [ActiveWorkbook]!BASE_Start.BaseTabSelection
> The actual MacroLink variable value: [ActiveWorkbook]!BASEStart.BaseTabSelection

This usually happens when the sheet name and the code name are different. I believe that `BASE_Start` is your sheet name and the code name of the worksheet is `BASEStart`.

[image]

Go to VBE and change the Sheet Codename from there and then try it again :)

I believe this is similar to what it looks now for you.

[image]

Change from here

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the code name and sheet name are the same.

Comment: May I see your file?